# get Input values dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I am devolping a web application using symfony framework. I have aproblem in forms. Here is my code:

```
$('#bookCleaningForm').submit(function() {
    // get the array of all the inputs 
    var $inputs = $('#bookCleaningForm :input[type=text]');

    // get an associative array of the values
    var values = {};
    var allVAlues='';
    $inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
            allVAlues = values[this.name];

    });
    alert(allValues);//console.log(allValues);
    saveBoookCleaning(allVAlues);

});
```

In the loop i got all data in allValues variable.But when I access outside the loop  i got only one value.

Please help

Comment: because you're overriding the previous values, so outside of the loop you'll get only the last value, to get all values outside of loop use `object` or `array` like you've used `values` object.

Comment: Can You Please Modify my Code.

Comment: Hi, what format would you like to store all of the values in?

Comment: I'll recommend you to use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form data, I guess you want to POST this data to server

Comment: I want send all values frther in ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time in the `each` loop you are assigning the variable `allValues` to the value of the current input. If you want to store the values as an array you could do this:

```
$('#bookCleaningForm').submit(function() {
  // get the array of all the inputs 
  var $inputs = $('#bookCleaningForm :input[type=text]');

  // get an associative array of the values
  var values = {};
  var allVAlues=[];
  $inputs.each(function() {
    values[this.name] = $(this).val();
        allVAlues.push(values[this.name]);

  });
  alert(allVAlues);//console.log(allValues);
  saveBoookCleaning(allVAlues);

});
```

Or, if you want them as a string:

```
$('#bookCleaningForm').submit(function() {
  // get the array of all the inputs 
  var $inputs = $('#bookCleaningForm :input[type=text]');

  // get an associative array of the values
  var values = {};
  var allVAlues='';
  $inputs.each(function() {
    values[this.name] = $(this).val();
        allVAlues += values[this.name];

  });
  alert(allVAlues);//console.log(allValues);
  saveBoookCleaning(allVAlues);

});
```